# jquery .parents()

Tags: jquery

I've got a list and a link, i want to change the top link:

```
<a class="topLink" href="#">change me</a>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link name</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click a 'link name' link, I want that text to be applied to the change me link.

How do I do this with jQuery parents? or what should I be using?

**Edit: Sorry, I forgot to say that I will have three of these lists, so three links that have a class of topLink**

Comment: what exactly does your markup look like here? that space gives me pause.

Comment: are you sure you understand what parents() does? take a deeper look in the documentation first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<ul>` and the `<a>` are adjacent siblings, then trythis:

```
$('ul').delegate('a','click',function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').prev().text( $(this).text() );
});
```

This uses [jQuery's `closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the first `<ul>` ancestor, and [jQuery's `.prev()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to traverse from the `<ul>` to its previous sibling.

If the HTML markup is any different from that which you've provided, then you need to give a sample of your actual HTML.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    $('.topLink').text($(this).text());
});
```

No need to invoke `.parents()` here (it wouldn't really work either)

by using `.delegate()` you can do the job by only binding one event handler to the parent `ul` element. Of course it would be much better if that `ul` had an id.

Ref.: [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
Example: [Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xhXbY/)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I will have three of these lists, so three links that have a class of topLink

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li a').click(function () {
    $(".topLink").html($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It already has a class, I wouldn't use parents since you would then have to get the parent's sibling (maybe jquery should have an uncle reference??? jk).

Using the class would be:

```
$('li a').click( function() {
    $('.topLink').text( $(this).text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `.closest()`

Answer (score 0):

the `anchor` tag you're trying to change isn't in the hierarchy of the LI so the `parents()` method won't pick it up. Your best bet would be to either select it by id or class and change the html value that way.